# largest possible domain of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

If k is the minimum value of the function

$$f(x)= \dfrac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}  + \dfrac{\cos x}{|\cos x|} + \dfrac{\tan x}{|\tan x|} + \dfrac{\cot x}{|\cot x|}$$  ,

**as x varies in the overall largest
possible domain of function**, then find |k|

This question can be solved by taking all possible value in all 4 quadrants , my doubt there is why this sentence `as x varies in the overall largest possible domain of function` what does this "overall largest possible domain " mean for a trignometric function ?

Comment: Are those supposed to be fractions? You can typeset a fraction as ```$\frac{ top }{ bottom }$``` to have it render as $\frac{ top }{ bottom }$.  I suspect largest possible domain just means where the expression is defined.

Comment: Please check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Per the comment of @Joe, assuming that you are presenting fractions, "overall largest possible domain" signifies that the problem composer has no idea how to specify a problem.  The composer's intent is probably that since you are not allowed to ever divide by $0$, any values of $x$ that result in either $\sin(x) = 0$ or $\cos(x) = 0$ must be disallowed from the domain.

Comment: Note that for $r \neq 0, ~\frac{r}{|r|}$ will either be $+1$ or $-1$ depending on whether $r$ is positive or negative.  To attack your problem, consider two cases: [1] $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ have the same sign (i.e. either both positive or both negative) [2] $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ have different signs.

Comment: When sin(x) and cos(x) both positive (quad 1), sum =4, both negative (quad. 3), sum =0, opposite sign (quad 2 or 4), sum =-2.   Question seems vague.